# MongoDB C# Driver QueryDocument greater than or less than

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using C# driver for MongoDB and I have the QueryDocument working to query a string using Query.Add but I am trying to dynamically build this out (which works if I am doing Add for = a value.  I want to do greater than or less than for a date check (dynamically).  See my code below.

I want to do a query.Add event (or some other event) to add to a query for the datetime check for greater than or less than.

NOTE:  I may be adding more values to search on other then the below so I know if I just search on LoanNumber I can ignore the date/time but I want to build out multiple search criteria.

For now I just need greater/less than using the C# driver, but pointers/help to where I can do other operations like regex or others would be helpful but not required (I can find these for generic MongoDB searches and other environments just not C# driver).

```
        var query = new QueryDocument();

        // check if there is anything in the loan number field and if so query that
        string LoanNumber = txtLoanNumber.Text.ToString();
        string StartDate = txtStatusChangeStartDate.Text.ToString();
        string EndDate = txtStatusChangeEndDate.Text.ToString();



        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoanNumber))
        {
            query.Add("LoanStatusAddedEvent.LoanNumber", LoanNumber);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StartDate))
        {
            query.Add("LoanStatusAddedEvent.StatusChangeDate", StartDate);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EndDate))
        {               
            query.Add(
                    -- saw this online to do it but it was a direct query and not adding to the Query.add
                    Query.LT("LoanStatusAddedEvent.StatusChangeDate", EndDate)
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query multiple lines try to do like this:

1. Collect your Query data:

   var queryList = new List();

   queryList.Add(Query.EQ("Attributes.AttributeName", attribute.AttributeName));
   queryList.Add(Query.EQ("Attributes2.AttributeName2", attribute2.AttributeName2));
2. Build your query:

   var query = new QueryBuilder();
   query.And(queryList);

After that you can use your query :)

I hope i can help with your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear, I can add multiple query options for multile items, the problem I am having is querying greater then or less than (or basically anything other then equal to.

Comment: Plus for some reason I am getting "List" not being found (red squigly lines under it) even though I added using System.Collections.Generic